# Sitemappath title

Tags: asp.net, resources, sitemap

I want to multilanguage my sitemappath with global resource how should I do this?

I tried this but doesn't work what do I wrong
web.sitmap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode title='$Resources: Resource, Home'  url="~/Home"  >
    <siteMapNode url="Login.aspx" title="$Resources: Resource, Login"  />
```

but if I do this I see ("Nothing" separator "Nothing")

Answer (score 1):

web.sitemap:

```
<siteMap enableLocalization="true"....
```